# Running flask as a subprocess in order to start a tkinter window

Tags: python, forms, flask, tkinter, subprocess

I have an application, working with python 3.7 and flask, that runs locally. I'd like to ask the user (myself) to give a path to a folder. I know how to use tkinter when running only python, I know how to send the data from flask to the python script and so on, but I cant find a way to run tkinter in this context.

I know that **tkinter is supposed to run in the main thread**, and I've tried working with subprocess in order to have tkinter window as the main thread, and flask as a subprocess.

Currently, I'm launching my script `main.py`, who launch flask as a subprocess with `subprocess.Popen()`. But even then, since the tkinter window is open from a flask route, it is obviously not the main thread. My main thread is a Loop waiting for a user input to exit the script and kill flask.exe ...

```py
@app.route('/getPath', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getPath():
    prompter = promptlib.Files()
    myPath = prompter.dir()
    return render_template('form.html', data={'path': myPath})
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this ? Even by replacing the tkinter window by another module, JavaScript or anything allowing the user to browse the windows explorer to select the path.

Comment: You just described [`<input type="file">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Comment: Thank you @aaron, I've only looked at Flask documentation and the file upload from Flask documentation was the exact opposite of what I wanted ... This is exactly what I needed !

Comment: @aaron The solution you linked allows me to get the file, I've also read about `webkitdirectory` to get all the content of a directory and it's children, but is it possible to get it's path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @aaron said, you want `<input type="file">`. However, in order to do this, you need to have server side code to handle this data. [Flask-WTForms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/) helps with this. Basically, in your code, you first make a class:

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
class UploadFileClass(FlaskForm): # Create a class based on the FlaskForm base we imported earlier
    file = FileField("Select a file", validators=[FileRequired()]) # Now we create a file field. 
    # The first argument is the label, and the second one is any validators you may want
    # For more info on validators, see https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/form/#validation
```

And now, in your route, allow `POST` requests:

```py
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def route():
    ...
```

Next, import your form (at the top of the file preferably) and add code to handle your file in the route:

```py
# ... in your route ...
form = UploadFileClass() # Make a new instance of the class

if form.validate_on_submit(): # If the form was successfully sent
    data = form.file.data # Get the data
    data.save("wherever") # Save the data
```

Refer to the [Creating Forms section of the docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/form/#file-uploads) for more information on creating a form.